# conflicting types data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default] type defaults to 'int'

Tags: c, microcontroller

I have a pointer called slave_buffer as global variable in my main.c file as follows:

```
l_u8 *slave_buffer = 0;

slave_buffer = lld_response_buffer;
```

and inside my main function I have placed values into my buffer as follows:

```
slave_buffer[1] = 0x12;
slave_buffer[2] = 0x34;
```

I have my lld_response_buffer declared and defined in another source file called uart.c

```
extern l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];

l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];
```

I already included the file uart.c in my main file.

But when I build my project, I can see the following errors

```
conflicting types for 'slave_buffer' (data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default] type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'slave_buffer' [-Wimplicit-int]) initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

and `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector` at the point where I placed my values into the slave_buffer.

Here is complete main.c file:

```
#include "derivative.h"  include peripheral declarations 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "uart.h"
#include "uart.c"

#define LED0_TOGGLE     OUTPUT_TOGGLE(PORT_C,16)
#define LED0_OFF        OUTPUT_CLEAR(PORT_C,16)
#define LED0_ON         OUTPUT_SET(PORT_C,16)

/**********************************************************************************************
* Global variables
**********************************************************************************************/
l_u8 ret;
l_u8 i;
l_u8 LED_counter;
l_u8 *slave_buffer = 0;

slave_buffer = lld_response_buffer;



void application_timer_FTM0()
{
    SIM_SCGC |= SIM_SCGC_FTM0_MASK; 
    FTM0_SC |= FTM_SC_PS(7);    

    FTM0_C0SC |= FTM_CnSC_CHIE_MASK; 
    FTM0_C0SC |= FTM_CnSC_MSA_MASK;         

    FTM0_C0V = FTM_CnV_VAL(391) ;       
    FTM0_SC |= FTM_SC_CLKS(1); 


    NVIC_ICPR |= 1 << ((INT_FTM0-16)%32);
    NVIC_ISER |= 1 << ((INT_FTM0-16)%32);
}


void GPIO_Init()
{
        CONFIG_PIN_AS_GPIO(PORT_C,16,OUTPUT); 

        LED0_OFF;                           
}



int main(void)
{
    l_u8 i, ret;
    l_u8 vector_number;

    Clk_Init();
    GPIO_Init();
    ret = l_sys_init();  

    ret = l_ifc_init(LI0);



    vector_number = INT_UART0 -16;


    NVIC_ICPR |= 1 << (vector_number%32);   
    NVIC_ISER |= 1 << (vector_number%32);
    application_timer_FTM0();

    for(;;)
    {               

        slave_buffer[0] = 2;
        slave_buffer[1] = 0x12;
        slave_buffer[2] = 0x34;
        uart_tx_response();

    }       
    return 0;
}


void FTM0_IRQHandler()
  {     
    if (1==((FTM0_C0SC & FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK)>>FTM_CnSC_CHF_SHIFT) )  
    {
        (void)FTM0_C0SC;                            
        FTM0_C0SC ^= FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK;             
        FTM0_C0V = FTM0_C0V + 391 ; 

        if (LED_counter>=50){

            LED0_TOGGLE;
            LED_counter = 0;
        }
        LED_counter++;
    }
  }
```

And I have these declared in uart.c file

```
l_u8          *response_buffer = 0;
extern l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];

l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];
response_buffer = lld_response_buffer;
```

and *response_buffer is being used in some functions in uart.c file

Comment: Please give a [mcve] which recreates the same error message. Note the word **complete**. This means the example must compile as it is and only give the same error message that you are asking about.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. In one place you say it is an array; in one place you say it is a pointer. These are not the same even though they are closely related.

Comment: Can i typecast an array from pointer?

Comment: "*... nor vector*" what does a C compiler refer to with "vector"?

Comment: This raises red flags: *"I already included the file uart.c in my main file."* Only headers are typically *included*, `.c` source files are compiled separately and resulting object files are *linked* together.

Comment: In most contexts, you get an (automatic) *conversion* of an array to a pointer to its first element.  No cast is needed, nor is one usually appropriate.  But you do need to define your objects' types consistently.  Putting your declarations into headers helps a great deal with this.

Comment: Hold on. You have this in the same file? : "extern l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];

l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];"

Comment: Your code contains an executable statement (`slave_buffer = lin_lld_response_buffer;`) at file scope.  This is not allowed.  You can provide *initializers* for file-scope variables, in their declarations, but executable statements must appear inside functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Why don't you provide this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of problems here.

- First of all, avoid using spaghetti globals with `extern` all over the place. This is very bad practice and the cause of all your problems.
- If you choose spaghetti programming design, then at least `extern l_u8 lld_response_buffer[10];` needs to be in the h file, not the c file.
- Then you have an assignment at file scope: `slave_buffer = lld_response_buffer;`. This is not an initialization, so it cannot be placed there. You cannot execute code at file scope, only initialize variables.
- You should never include c files for any reason. It doesn't make sense and will cause linker errors.
- Empty `()` parenthesis after functions is obsolete style. It shouldn't be used in C (but is fine in C++). It means "this function accepts any parameters and will merrily crash when you give it any parameter other than void".

Overall the design needs to be re-done from scratch. It seems you are sharing an UART buffer from a driver with all of the world. If so, don't do that.

To get the current program working with a quick & dirty fix (not recommended), you should remove `extern` and the c file inclusion. Then add:

```
// in uart.h:
l_u8* get_response_buffer (void);

// in uart.c:
l_u8* get_response_buffer (void)
{
  return lld_response_buffer;
}
```

Inside a function in main, add `slave_buffer =get_response_buffer();`. main.c only includes "uart.h".

But as mentioned, if this is an UART rx buffer you shouldn't spew it all over the program, 1) since it doesn't belong all over the program and 2) you'll most likely need to implement protection mechanisms against race conditions when accessing the buffer and likely some sort of double-buffering. This needs to be implemented inside the driver and nowhere else.

Make sure all your header files have "header guards".

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the problem is gone and my compiler give no errors now. I defined the following

```
l_u8 *slave_buffer = 0;

slave_buffer = lld_response_buffer;
```

inside my main function and not as global variables.

It can be explained with a small example

for example consider my main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "extern.h"
int x;
x=10;
int main()
{
    print();
    printf("\n X in the file extern_main.c is %d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

my extern.c file

```
#include <stdio.h> 
extern int x;  
int x;
void print()
{   
x = 9;
printf("\n x in extern.c is %d",x);
}
```

my extern.h file

```
void print();
```

Compiling my main.c file will give the same error as shown in [image]

It will not throw the error if x is given a value inside the main function instead of defining it globally and initialising it globally, as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "extern.c" 
void print();
int main()
{
    int x;
    x=10;
    print();
    printf("\n X in the file extern_main.c is %d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

my extern.c file

```
#include <stdio.h> 
extern int x;  
int x;
void print()
{   
x = 9;
printf("\n x in extern.c is %d",x);
}
```

my extern.h file

```
void print();
```